# How to calculate consecutive sum in R?

Tags: r, sum

If for example I have a vector of numbers.

```
c(1:9)
```

Now, if I want to compute sum of three consecutive number in the following way:

```
(1+2+3,4+5+6,7+8+9)
```

how should I approach?

Comment: Probably better to use `colSums(matrix(1:9,nrow=3))` instead of `rowSums(matrix(1:9,nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))`.

Comment: I like games :) `sapply(0:2, function(x) sum(c(1:9)[(3*x+1):(3*x+3)]))` gives: `6 15 24`

Comment: None of these have conditional statements. @BenBolker you needed `colSums` instead

Comment: Here are a cpuple more: `tapply(1:9, (seq_along(1:9)-1) %/% 3 , sum)` and `library(zoo); rollapply(1:9, 3, sum, by = 3)`

Comment: @rawr: oops.  Why should they have conditional statements??

Comment: @BenBolker no, that was a response to OP who subsequently deleted his comment, ha.

Comment: I bet there's (warning: games again) a `Reduce` method  :-)

Comment: `plyr`, `dplyr`, `data.table`, ...

Comment: someone could put this up on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: My 2c: 3*((1:9)[1:9%%3==0]-1) or 3*(seq(1,9,by=3)+1)- just cause 3 is a lovely number

Answer (score 1):

I learned to use this one correctly:

```
foo<-1:9
aggregate(foo,by=list(rep(1:3,each=3) ),FUN=sum)
```

For a longer input,  do this:

```
function (x,len) aggregate(x,by=list(rep(1:(length(x)/len),each=len) ),FUN=sum)
```

And because I'm still waiting for what-if.xkcd.com to update, here's the timings:
(and I did check that all calculate the right thing)

```
x<-1:99
len<-3
 microbenchmark(shadow(x,len),rawr(x,len),groth(x,len),carl(x,len),times=10)
Unit: microseconds
           expr      min       lq    median       uq      max
 shadow(x, len)   62.006   70.130   75.0480   97.926  180.884
   rawr(x, len)  541.797  564.033  571.9445  585.842  639.295
  groth(x, len)  514.002  525.548  547.5705  551.633  568.310
   carl(x, len) 1045.536 1099.844 1120.5840 1166.553 1346.582
 neval
    10
    10
    10
    10
```

So the `matrix -- colSums` is fastest.  I'll leave it to someone else to figure out the memory requirements of each approach.